# First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty on render

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On the update action of the Video controller, I have written -->

```
  def update
    if current_user.video.update_attributes(video_params)
      flash[:success] = "Video App Updated!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

However, the render :edit part seems to be throwing out an error. It says :

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
Extracted source (around line #6):


  <div class="row">
    <div class="span6 offset3">
      <%= form_for(@video) do |f| %> # line 6
```

I'm assuming I'm not quite understanding what the render is doing. This is what my edit action looks like -->

```
  def edit
    @video = current_user.video
  end
```

What do you guys think? Still a noob, much appreciated :)

Comment: I think you are not getting any values in "@video" variable

Comment: Hey Mihir. Here's the weird part though. If I just load the edit view,    everything is working. But, once I update and it goes through render,then it no longer gives any value for @video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `render :edit` will show the `edit.html.erb` view, but the `edit` action is not executed. The `edit.html.erb` is expecting a `@video` variable that is not set in the `update` action, that's why you have this error. There is 2 solutions:

**Set the `@video` variable in the `update_action`**

```
def update
  @video = current_user.video
  if @video.update_attributes(video_params)
    flash[:success] = "Video App Updated!"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

or

**Redirect to the `edit` action when update fails**

```
def update
  if current_user.video.update_attributes(video_params)
    flash[:success] = "Video App Updated!"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    flash[:alert] = current_user.video.errors.full_messages.join('\n')
    redirect_to :action => :edit, :id => current_user.video.id
  end
end
```

If the `edit` was complex, the second solution would be better because it avoids duplication. In your case, the first solution is good also.

The difference between `render` and `redirect_to` is explained in [Guide Layouts and Rendering in Rails 2.3.2](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-redirect-to)

Comment: Redirecting isn't really good solution as it won't display validation errors this way.

Comment: @MarekLipka You're right. I've added a flash message to fix this problem, but that's a dirty solution. The first solution is better.

Comment: If the edit was complex, I would consider extracting its logic to some other method instead of modifying application flow by introducing redirection.

Answer (score 1):

You don't set `@video` variable on `update` action, so it's `nil`. You should have:

```
def update
  @video = current_user.video
  if current_user.video.update_attributes(video_params)
    flash[:success] = "Video App Updated!"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

You should remember that rendering other action's template in controller **doesn't run the code of that action**. So, if you have

```
render :edit
```

the partial `edit` will be rendered, but controller code for this action (setting `@video`) won't run.

Comment: Thanks Marek! You've been helping me out the whole day :)

Answer (score -1):

I have the same type of condition and i have done it like this. and its working in my case

```
def update
  @video = current_user.video
  respond_to do |format|
    if @video.update_attributes(video_params)
      format.html { redirect_to root_url }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Mihir. May I ask, why write the respond_to do |format| ?

Comment: If we need result in different format then we use respond_to fo |format| style. I mean in js format or json format etc....